# Is there a more efficient way of bulk update in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Suppose I have an array of user objects and a sequelize model User with id and name. Is there a more efficient way of doing update than the below?

```
let users = [{id: 1, name: 'John Doe'},{id: 2, name: 'Mary'}...]
users.map(user => {
   User.update(user, { where: { id: user.id } });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `bulkCreate`

Your case can be rewritten like:

```
User.bulkCreate(users, {updateOnDuplicate: true})
```

[Docs](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/model/#bulkcreaterecords-options-promisearrayinstance)

Comment: does it determine if it is duplicate based on the primary key?

Comment: `updateOnDuplicate` is determined on *any* UNIQUE KEY or PRIMARY KEY